# Alexa deploy to us-west-2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

How can I deploy my Alexa skill to the `us-west-2` region using the ASK CLI? According to [this post on the amazon forums](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/173679/ask-cli-does-not-deploy-to-eu-west-1-or-other-regi.html), I can specify `NA` as the deployment region, but it will deploy to `us-east-1`. Is there a way to specify the exact deployment region?

Comment: check out this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p22ZJSyVK5k

Comment: in the ask-cli you can edit the default region and/or set a different region to a second profile name.